# Passar array de String por parametro para tela2

Tags: android

estou seguindo um tutorial na internet e me surgiu uma pequena duvida que é o seguinte.
No tutorial, eu coloco itens de um array de String em um listview e nela consigo selecionar varias opcoes pelo simple_list_item_checked.

Eu estou conseguindo mostrar qual estao selecionados e os que não estao selecionados, o que eu precisava é jogar todos os selecionados para uma outra tela, o problema é como jogar como String[], porque no exemplo ele esta apenas como uma String

O que eu preciso entao é jogar todos os estados para a tela2 como o tipo String[]

Alguem me ajuda? please?

```
listaEstados = new String[]{"São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Minas Gerais", "Rio Grande do Sul", "Santa Catarina", "Paraná"};

public void onClickMarcados(View view){
    String listaEstadosSelec = "";

    //Cria um array com os itens selecionados no listview
    SparseBooleanArray selecionados = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i=0; i<selecionados.size(); i++){
        //Pega os itens marcados
        listaEstadosSelec = listaEstadosSelec + listaEstados[selecionados.keyAt(i)]+", ";
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tela2_Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("itens", listaEstadosSelec);
    startActivity(intent);

    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Estados marcados: "+listaEstadosSelec, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tela2_Activity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("itens",new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList(listaEstadoSelec)));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Do outro lado, você faz:

```
     ArrayList<String> estados  = getExtras().getStringArrayList("itens");
```

Comment: Não deu muito certo não amigo, da o seguinte erro:
The method putStringArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<String>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>)

Comment: Ah tah, perdão , vou corrigir na resposta

Comment: É por que o método Arrays.asList retorna um List e não um ArrayList. Então, basta fazer uma nova instância de ArrayList  colocando o tipo (importante nesse caso) e passando o List retornado para o construtor.

Comment: Entendido, deu certo amigo.. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de utilizar um *String* com os valores separados por virgula, utilize um *ArrayList* e passe-o usando `intent.putStringArrayListExtra()`:

```
listaEstados = new String[]{"São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Minas Gerais", "Rio Grande do Sul", "Santa Catarina", "Paraná"};

public void onClickMarcados(View view){

    //ArrayList para receber os itens selecionados
    ArrayList<String> listaEstadosSelec = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Cria um array com os itens selecionados no listview
    SparseBooleanArray selecionados = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i=0; i<selecionados.size(); i++){

        //Pega os itens marcados e adiciona ao ArrayList
        listaEstadosSelec.add(listaEstados[selecionados.keyAt(i)]);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tela2_Activity.class);

    //Usa o putStringArrayListExtra() para passar o ArrayList
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("itens", listaEstadosSelec);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Muito bom @ramaral, era exatamente isso que eu precisava, não descartando a outra boa ajuda... ^^